# Video plays when video is shown, when video is hidden, it pauses?

Tags: jquery, video, hide, show, playback

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/DW5CV/15/

Here there is a kind of slideshow of art work that contains divs with images and videos. When the user clicks on the full screen image or video it hides and shows the next in line, and continues on a loop. The videos are set at auto play, however I want them to auto play when they are shown and pause when they are hidden?

```
$(function () {

 var win = $(window),
    fullscreen = $('.full'),
    image = fullscreen.find('img, video'),
    imageWidth = image.width(),
    imageHeight = image.height(),
    imageRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

function resizeImage() {
    var winWidth = win.width(),
        winHeight = win.height(),
        winRatio = winWidth / winHeight;

    if (winRatio > imageRatio) {
        image.css({
            width: winWidth,
            height: Math.round(winWidth / imageRatio)
        });
    } else {
        image.css({
            width: Math.round(winHeight * imageRatio),
            height: winHeight
        });
    }
}

$('.full').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    if($(this).next('.full').length === 1)
        $(this).next('.full').show();
    else
        $('.full').eq(0).show();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't want each video to play as soon as they're loaded on the page. So, I took `autoplay` out from the `<video>` elements.

Here's what I came up with to play/pause videos on each of your "slides" ('.full')

http://jsfiddle.net/zyglobe/DW5CV/22/

```
function advanceToSlide(slidePos){
    slide = $('.full').eq(slidePos);
    slide.show();
    var video = $('video', slide);

    $('video').each(function(){
        $(this).get(0).pause();
    })

    if(video.length){
        console.log(video.get(0).play());
    }


}

$('.full').on('click', function(){
    $('.full').hide();
    if(currentSlide < numSlides - 1){
        currentSlide = currentSlide + 1;
    } else{
        currentSlide = 0;
    }
    advanceToSlide(currentSlide);
});
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but it works. You might look into using an existing jQuery slideshow solution.

Comment: There is one slight issue, the images and videos are no longer full screen. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: No problem. Looks like your function "resizeImage" is working.  It's just not being called anywhere.  You can add it (`resizeImage()`) at the bottom within the self-invoking function (`$(function(){});`)

Comment: Could you possible show me how this looks on the fiddle? Also I notice that when the page loads all the images and videos are displayed if you scroll down. How can they all be hidden from the start except the first one? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is closer. However it does not resize if you resize the browser, but it resizes if you refresh the browser at a different size?